# Unintended Indents with Plain Text Email

Tags: email, plaintext

I have a function that will send plain text and HTML emails.  When coding, I indent code to get proper nesting.  Note the two code strings below.

```
$plain_text = '
*Hi ' . show_user_name($user_id) . '. Thanks for signing up!*
';

$plain_text = '
    *Hi ' . show_user_name($user_id) . '. Thanks for signing up!*
';
```

When the second one is sent as plain text email, the line "*Hi...." is indented.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it's indented because you indented it!

In plain-text email messages (unlike HTML), white space is preserved and significant, so if you don't want leading spaces, strip them from your content:

```
$plain_text = preg_replace('/^ +/m', '', $plain_text);
```

You need the `m` modifier to apply the leading space stripping to each line in the body.

Alternatively, don't indent in the first place - the indenting of your code doesn't have to be related to the format of the text that you generate:

```
$plain_text =
    '*Hi ' . show_user_name($user_id) . '. Thanks for signing up!*';
```

If you're using tabs for indents, you could filter those out too:

```
$plain_text = preg_replace('/^[ \t]+/m', '', $plain_text);
```

Comment: No, has nothing to do with charset. How exactly doesn't this work? Can you demonstrate that *not* stripping leading spaces?

Comment: In my original post, I had to space the text over, but in Notepad++, I typically tab over to create proper nesting.  Is that related?

Comment: I've expanded my answer - indenting your code and indenting within your message are entirely independent things.

Comment: `$plain_text = preg_replace('/^[ \t]+/m', '', $plain_text);` did it.  I don't know much about `preg_replace()`, so I didn't think of that as an option here.  Thanks!